# How to detect mouse clicks in EMGU.CV CvInvoke.Imshow window with C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a yolo application built with EmguCv 4.8 in .NET6 that detects objects from a camera stream.
Is there a way to detect mouse clicks and other events eg mouse down/up on the built in **CvInvoke.Imshow** window?
If not should i use my own frame viewer eg MediaElement or ImageViewer in a WinForm or WPF app?